# How to run cmd as admin

Tags: cmd

I use Windows 10 and in cmd I want to use the command

```
sfc /scannow
```

Cmd then gives me this message

> You must be an administrator running a console session in order to use the sfc utility.

I then try to open cmd by right-clicking and press Run as Administrator. 
But then I get this error. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: did you try right clicking on the windows icon if the bottom-left corner and then run as admin?

Comment: I right-clicked on the cmd icon and press Run as Administrator.

Comment: Have you installed a program that overtakes your cmd.exe? What is `Kommandoprompt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the error is not related to `cmd.exe` running as admin. You probably have something incorrectly assigned to that specific shortcut.

Below is the correct way of running `cmd.exe` as *Admin* on **Windows 8** and **Windows 10**

On your keyboard press <kbd>windows key</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd> then select <kbd>Command Prompt (Admin)</kbd> from the list.
Alternatively right click on the start button and select the above mentioned.

This allows your to run `cmd.exe` as administrator. and you can then run

```
sfc /SCANNOW
```

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the Command Prompt icon and select Run as administrator

[image]

Comment: When I do this I get the error as shown in the picture above.

Comment: try using-  sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows

Comment: When I type "sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows" in cmd, it gives me the same message as above.

Comment: I don't get this... He shows you that he has an issue when rightclicking and selecting Runas, then you give an answer telling him to do what he did?